# delete data based on sum of values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I would like to ask if it possible to delete some data based on sum in big query.
Here is the problem I would like to delete only rows which has sum over 100. I try to use:

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT user, sum(paid) as money FROM test) where money > 100
```

but it didn't work  then I try use:

```
with table2 as (SELECT a.*, sum(paid) as money from `test` a)
DELETE from table2 where table2.money > 100
```

it also didn't work

| id | login | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 99 |
| 1 | john | 2 |
| 2 | josh | 50 |
| 3 | mark | 800 |

and the result should be only 1 row here.

Answer (score 1):

Try below SQL to delete data from *test* where sum(paid) > 100.
Once it executed, perform select on *test* table to see the result.

```
delete from `test` 
where id in (select distinct id 
             from `test` 
             group by id
             having sum(paid) > 100)
```